# Different fields with same numbers in proto

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'm making a .proto file to decode a protobuf binary message automatically. To see the structure of the message and add the correct field numbers, I'm using https://protobuf-decoder.netlify.app/. A few layers down, I see the same field number repeated multiple times. I need the field number 21 in the first field with the number 4. But how do I tell the file which field number 4 to decode?

Recreation of how the file looks

```
  /  1
 |   2
 |   3 
 |
 |      /  1
 |   4 <   2
8       \  21 //this is what I need
 |
 |   4  /   1
 |      \   25
 |
 |      /   1
 |   4 <    2
  \      \  11
```

This is what I'm trying to use but it's not working.

```
message Layer1 {
    Layer2 layer = 8;
}

message Layer2 {
    Layer3 layer = 4;
}

message Layer3 {
    string user = 21;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These variables with the same field number may represent "repeated" variables in the proto file, meaning that they come from an array.